# ssmtp for windows

Tags: windows, smtp, relay

I have the following problem with a software that should do mail notification for a biometric entry system:
the software does currently only support SMTP over port 25 without TLS/SSL. Which is bad because port 25 is blocked in our network due spam reason and our mailserver only support TLS / SSL logins.

so i need a solution to connect to a localhost smtp server which just relays to my ssl host on port 587. 
i know there is ssmtp for linux, but i need it for windows, because the server app for this biometric stuff only runs on windows...

edit: i know there is the IIS SMTP Server, but maybe something different?

Comment: Also, I see no reason for the Windows requirement. SMTP is a network protocol; the program could contact a SMTP server running on a different machine in the same LAN -- not necessarily on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

A full SMTP server is unnecessary – use [`stunnel`](http://www.stunnel.org/), which can unwrap SSL from any protocol.

```
[smtp]
  accept = 25
  connect = fooserver:587
  client = yes
  protocol = smtp
```

(`verify = 2` is highly recommended)

Comment: does it support SMTP SASL auth?

Comment: @reox: No, stunnel only strips SSL, but relays the SMTP session verbatim - it's up to your program to authenticate correctly. (You did not mention whether the program supports SMTP AUTH.)